# How to parse a javascript file that contains json data stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, magento

I was wondering how can I extract the JSON data from a javascript file. The javascript is intended to be used as a config file and contains one variable with JSON data in it. This is similar to the require-config.js file used in Magento 2, just for reference. It looks something like this:

```
var config = {
    fieldsets : [
        {
            title :  'Quote Essentials',
            description : 'Some',
            fields : [
                {
                    label : 'What type of project is this for?',
                    required : true,
                    class : '',
                    type : 'input',
                    inputType : 'text',
                    hint : 'For example: company uniforms, clothing line, school events, etc.',
                    id : ''
                },
                {
                    label : 'How many total items do you need?',
                    required : true,
                    class : '',
                    type : 'input',
                    inputType : 'text',
                    hint : 'Please note: the minimum order size is 24 pieces.',
                    id : ''
                },
...
```

Comment: This isn’t JSON.

Comment: I know , it is a javascript file that has a variable that contains json data.

Comment: Where do you need to extract that? In browser? On server?

Comment: No, it's a JS object. There's no JSON anywhere there.

Comment: @Andy yes, true. My bad for saying is json. and I have a client side script that would read this file and parse the javascript object

Comment: If this file is client-side too then add it before all the other scripts and access it with `config.fieldsets...` etc like you would any other object. Although, if you can edit that file, I would probably namespace it so it's not stuck as a global var.

Comment: @Andy Could you please show me how I would namespace it? I am trying to avoid having it as a global variable. I was thinking to get it using ajax but I just don't know how to extract the object

Comment: And I also know that converting it to json format would solve the problem, but I am just trying to explore other options here :D

Comment: It only really works if the rest of your code is namespaced too, otherwise there's probably not much point.

Comment: Here. I won't add it as a answer, [but this is what I mean](https://gist.github.com/andywillis/8e240688b9aadd15083470c3a2e28611).

Comment: ohh I see what you mean. But, this way I would have to include the script inside my html right? I am trying to avoid the file being "visible" by any one inspecting the page's code

Comment: Not possible with client-side scripts. You could obfuscate the data with an online tool, but really if there's data in there that no-one should see you need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're accessing this server-side you can export the config

```
module.exports = {
  fieldset: [ ... ]
}
```

and `require` it

```
const config = require('./config.js');
```

If you're trying to access it on the client-side, just place the config script before the scripts that access it and you'll be able to access it like you would any other object:

```
config.fieldset...
```

One problem with this is that you're adding the `config` variable directly to `window` and by doing this you might be over-writing an existing `config` variable. Probably unlikely, but a way to mitigate this is to provide a namespace for your code so you don't pollute the global namespace and the code becomes more modularised. WRT to your config file, your namespace technique might work like this:

```
// Semi-colon to prevent minify issues
// Pass `window` into the immediately-invoked function expression
// as an argument
;(function (window) {

   // config is local to this function and can't leak    
   var config = { ... };

   // If the `app` variable isn't available, create it
   window.app = window.app || {};

   // Add config to the app namespace
   window.app.config = config;

})();
```

And you can do something similar to the rest of your code.

You would access the config with `app.config.fieldset...`.

Hope that helps.